# What to do when uninstalling rubygems-update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Agile development with rails is telling me to enter the following command on Mac

```
sudo gem uninstall rubygems-update
```

to which terminal responds, "in addition to the gem? [Yn]"

How do I know whether to keep the 'gem' or not? I've never done anything like this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer to the question is yes, it is asking you if you want to remove the executables in addition to the gem.  Kind of a silly question to me, not sure why you would want to keep the executables without the gem behind them

Comment: Like I said I'm a n00b at this sort of thing. I don't get why it's telling me to uninstall in the installing portion of this book. I will accept your answer, thank you.

Comment: i didn't mean your question, i meant the system asking you if you want to keep the executables :) I realize you didn't know what it was asking you.